# Laravel one-to-one relationship giving errors

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Im trying to implement a one-to-one relationship, im calling it from a 'command' and i keep getting a Undefined property error when viewing any record in that relationship.

In my model i have the following

```
public function preferences()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\WebsitePreferences', 'id', 'website_id');
}
```

Then im calling it as such

```
    $websites = Website::where('active', 1)->get();

    foreach ($websites as $website) {

        var_dump($website->preferences()->status);

    }
```

the exact error is as follows

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne::$status
```

If i do a var_dump($website) it returns all the values in that table, just not the ones in the WebsitePreferences table associated with that 'Website'

I have a few other one-to-one relationships and they all work just fine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try doing `Website::with('preferences')->get()`

Answer (score 1):

When you call a relationship as a method, it returns the QueryBuilder instance. This allow you to keep chaining with where, with and so on.

Instead you should call it as an attribute:

```
$website->preferences->status
```

Comment: I tried that, and it returns Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: If i change it to $website->preferences['status'] it just returns NULL

Comment: what do you get with dd($website->preferences) ?

Comment: It returns null ... Could it be because im running it from a command? do i have to implement anything to make it work?

Comment: Hmmmm, i call it from a standard controller and it still doesnt work

Comment: Quick check: there actually is a preference linked to your website ?

Answer (score 0):

In your model try this:

```
public function preferences()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\WebsitePreferences', 'website_id');
}
```

In your controller:

```
Website::with('preferences')->get()
```

in your view:

```
 foreach ($websites as $website) {
     @php(dd($website->preferences->status)); }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function preferences()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\WebsitePreferences', 'id', 'website_id');
}


$websites = Website::where('active', 1)->get();
```

You need to check empty for relation

```
foreach ($websites as $website) {
     if(empty($website->preferences) === false){
       $website->preferences->status
    }
}
```